# What are the legal Ramifications if any, of ratifying the last remaining Un-ratified amendment of the Constitution?

Tags: constitutional-law, us-constitution, congress, us-house-of-reps

There were originally 12 articles proposed for ratification in the "bill of rights" ten were ratified soon after. One was ratified in 1992 and the remaining proposal has no deadline or date of expiration to be ratified and requires only one more state to accept it in order to be added to the Constitution.

The interesting part of this is that it would potentially increase  the number of representatives in the house of representatives from 425 to approximately 6,400.

My question is as follows;

What are the possible consequences (positive and/or negative) and of the house of representatives being increased in such a drastic way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) because it isn't about law, it seems to be about political structure.

Comment: @ron Beyer it's about law.... The United States Constitution is the basis of all law. The Supreme Court determines the validity of all laws through the reading and interpretation of the Constitution.

Comment: I understand that, but it is a hypothetical question about the "consequences" of a political action. That alone is too broad, SE is about questions/answers not discussions. It would be like asking "what if congress made walking backwards illegal". Obviously the idea of 1 rep for every 50,000 people was thought about at a time when they couldn't imagine 300 million residents. It was never ratified because it simply would not work, there are a lot of amendments proposed that were DOA, this was just an early one. 6400 reps would basically mean the collapse of the house into chaos.

Comment: @ron Bayer 1. The question stands to have merit, though it is broad it still has a basis in Law. I would agree that it could be placed in a political SE, but the answer that  I am looking for is one that is founded upon legal premise not political "philosophy"

Comment: I am interested in the Legal consequence of such an action as opposed to a theoretical discussion on what it would entail. It is not about "IF" BUT "WHEN" THE AMENDMENT IS RATIFIED and what effect it would have on the current Laws that is in question. I am interested in knowing what would happen if the countries citizens went from being represented by one house member for every 700,000 U.S residents to one per every 50,000 residents, but that is not the only thing being asked within the question I posted.

Comment: @PeopleCallMeAdam just because something flows from the law or must comply with the law doesn't make it a legal question. the legal consequences of such a change are zero - congress would still pass laws, enforced by the administration and decided by the judiciary. Whether there are 425 or 6,400 or 3 or 2.6 million representatives is of no legal consequence. How it would work is a political question.

Comment: The effect ratifying this amendment would have is that the amendment would be ratified. Unless you have specific laws you think would change based on that, that's the end of the question. The consequences of such an action - what you're explicitly asking for - aren't on topic here.

Comment: As is obvious by the comments I am in the wrong here, I will do some research and try to word the question in a manner that fits the "Legal" guidelines of the "Law" section of SE. Though I would like to point out a few things. I am looking for a response coming from the perspective of a "Legal" standing not a "political" standing. Responses based on "Law" tend to be based on objective reasoning rather than subjectively interpreting a political "opinion" as to what might happen as a result. I am interested in discovering if there would be any restructuring of the current "LAW" as a result

Comment: The irony in the situation is that it seems as though the ones participating in the subject "cannot see the forest through the trees" technicalities in the wording of the question have caused intelligent individuals to over think the true intentions of the question. "What happens when the amendment is passed?" It's not about "IF" as is obvious by the previous amendment passed in 1992. If it happens 4537 years from now what would it mean for the rest of the Constitution? That is the real question being asked here. Not a political gossip group stroking egos....

Comment: Assume the amendment is ratified. In what way could it effect other Laws? Will other laws be effected in any way? Will "congress" have to change the structuring of the Senate? Would it be easier or harder for the house of representatives to pass bills/laws? Would it require new laws to enforce or regulate the changes? Would there be a need to change the number of electoral votes/voters? Do you believe that not one single law would be effected if the amendment was ratified? If our current law is changed or interpreted differently then it would seem that the question stands to have merit right?

Comment: @PeopleCallMeAdam Well 4537 years from now who even knows what kind of laws are on the books. Or what amendments have been made. We've had 27 already, at the same pace we'd add over 500 more in that span of time. It's already a stretch of the imagination to think one country will even last that long under the same constitution.  And a general rule on any stack exchange is that hypothetical future situations are off-topic.  We're here to answer, not debate and conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

The legal consequence of ratifying this amendment is that it would become the 28th Amendment to the US constitution.

That simply means that there would be a number of elections with lots of election maps re-drawn. Also, the Capital building would likely have to be enlarged to accommodate more representatives.

Since ratification laws are based on the fraction of votes, it would not affect ratifying other laws.

There are no legal "ramifications."